# change background color of 2 textviews, every 2nd click (like in table tennis)

Tags: android

i want to change the background color of 2 textviews, every 2nd click, because i'm making a scoreboard and want to change the player service every 2 points (like in table tennis).

how do you do this in the activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a boolean as a flag and swap it between true and false.  Alternatively, if the total number of clicks is useful to you, you can use an incremented integer to keep track of them, and check it like `if (iCount%2 == 0)` (matches 0,2,4,6 etc.)

Also, you can set the background color with something like this

```
textView.setBackgroundColor(0xfff00000)
```

or like this

```
textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
```

if you have a color.xml file set up with colours in it.